# How CodeIgniter close db connections?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm wondering how CodeIgniter close db connections. In the doc, it says "CodeIgniter intelligently takes care of closing your database connections". But how does CodeIgniter do this? Seems I didn't find the db driver's `close` method get called in CodeIgniter 3.0.3 source code.

Comment: Its automatic or you can use $this->db->close()

Comment: @Exprator What I'm wondering is how it's "automatic" closed. I would like know the magic under the hood. :)

Comment: "Intelligently" probably means "lets PHP close it", as PHP does that automatically when the script finishes running. You probably won't find code for it as a result.

Comment: @ceejayoz What if it's php-fpm?

Comment: @MouhongLin Same, unless you've specifically gone and turned on persistent connections. In which case you wouldn't *want* it automatically closed anyways.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks. Could you add your answer?

Answer (score 4):

Follow the code. If

```
$this->db->close()
```

is called for an action, first thing you should look is

```
DB.php
```

file with

```
CI_DB
```

class within. There you would see that there is no

```
close()
```

method and you should then make search in

```
DB_driver.php
```

file which holds

```
CI_DB_driver
```

class that is extended class by

```
CI_DB
```

class. And Eureca! method with code is there. :)
Of course, all these files are in system directory.

Comment: But I don't see `close` method is called. I added a log in the driver's `close` method, it's never called.

Comment: See where? Please edit your question with exact code used in case.